# Yii2 : Model returning NULL value (not set) when using Widget Detail VIew

Tags: mysql, yii2, detailview

i want to ask you about using `DetailView` Widget. I want to show data from join table, so i modified function `findModel($id)` like this :

```
protected function findModel($id)
{
    if (($model = TPQ::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        $data = $model::findBySql("SELECT * FROM tpq, kurikulum, pengurus where tpq.kurikulum_id = kurikulum.kurikulum_id and tpq.pengurus_id = pengurus.pengurus_id and tpq_id = $id")->all();
        return $data;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

I use the function in View

```
   public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }
```

My View :

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'TPQ_ID',
        'TPQ_NAMA',
        'TPQ_ALAMAT',
        'TPQ_KOORDINAT',
        'TPQ_BERDIRI',
        'TPQ_AKTIF',
        'KURIKULUM_NAMA',
        'KURIKULUM_DETAIL:ntext',
        'KURIKULUM_AKTIF',
        'PENGURUS_NAMA',
        'PENGURUS_ALAMAT',
        'PENGURUS_NOHP',
    ],
]) ?>
```

Fields in table TPQ : `'TPQ_ID', 'KURIKULUM_ID', 'PENGURUS_ID', 'TPQ_NAMA', 'TPQ_ALAMAT', 'TPQ_KOORDINAT', 'TPQ_BERDIRI', 'TPQ_AKTIF'`

Fields in table Pengurus : `'PENGURUS_ID','USER_ID','PENGURUS_NAMA','PENGURUS_ALAMAT','PENGURUS_NOHP'`

Fields in table Kurikulum : `'KURIKULUM_ID', 'KURIKULUM_NAMA', 'KURIKULUM_DETAIL', 'KURIKULUM_AKTIF'`

There is no error, but it shows 'not set' value. How i fix it?

Answer (score 4):

There are some problems with your code.

**1)** Use English for naming because it's international language. Think about other developers who may support this code and simply don't know this language.

**2)** It's better to replace `findBySql()` with `ActiveQuery` methods. Why `ActiveRecord` is needed if you don't use its features? I don't see any complex logic in your query, and even complex logic can be built with `ActiveQuery`.

**3)** For multiple tables you need to specify relations or display multiple `DetailView` widgets instead. This widget is designed to work with one model.

**4)** For displaying relations you can use dot notation or getters.

Example with dot notation:

```
'relation.attributeName',
```

Example with getter:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'attributeName',
    'value' => $model->relation->attributeName,
],
```

Read official docs for more details.